# $n^2 - n + 11$ is the product of four prime numbers, some of which may be the same. What is the minimum value of $n$?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

Let $n$ be a positive integer such that $n^2 - n + 11$ is the product of four prime numbers, some of which may be the same. What is the minimum value of $n$?

The problem is taken from [here](http://imc-official.chiuchang.org/files/problem/2008-IWYMIC-Individual.pdf). I know the answer is $132$, but how can I prove it? That would mean the four numbers are $11$, $11$, $11$, and $13$.

Can you give me a hint, please? Thanks!

Comment: $$n(n-1)+11$$ is odd, therefore none of the numbers are $2$

Comment: Further, none of the numbers are 3, since $n^2-n+11$ is never divisible by 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, find the smallest prime that divides $n^2-n+11$. It is not 2:

$$0^2-0+11 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$
$$1^2-1+11 \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$$

It is not 3:

$$0^2-0+11\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$
$$1^2-1+11\equiv 2\pmod{3}$$
$$2^2-2+11\equiv 1\pmod{3}$$

Not 5:

$$0^2-0+11\equiv 1\pmod{5}$$
$$1^2-1+11\equiv 1\pmod{5}$$
$$2^2-2+11\equiv 3\pmod{5}$$
$$3^2-3+11\equiv 2\pmod{5}$$
$$4^2-4+11\equiv 3\pmod{5}$$

Not 7:

$$0^2-0+11\equiv 4\pmod{7}$$
$$1^2-1+11\equiv 4\pmod{7}$$
$$2^2-2+11\equiv 6\pmod{7}$$
$$3^2-3+11\equiv 3\pmod{7}$$
$$4^2-4+11\equiv 2\pmod{7}$$
$$5^2-5+11\equiv 3\pmod{7}$$
$$6^2-6+11\equiv 6\pmod{7}$$

This means the smallest prime that divides $n^2-n+11$ is 11. So, you use trial and error:

$$n^2-n+11=11^4$$
has no solutions over the integers

$$n^2-n+11=11^3\cdot 13$$
Here you get 132.